# League of Legends website is giving me 'Not enough data to showcase your skills' on login?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just tried logging in to my LoL account and I got this message:

[image: Error Message]

This was my previous nickname but I change it in 14/11.

Is there another way to show my review? I have already pressed the "Retry" button several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I sent a ticket to riot and now I'm able to see the review. Thanks